# Google oauth + django - cant authenticate from saved data

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Okay, so i got the flow working, but it only works on the current session, if i try to load the data in, even with just a refresh the credentials dont hold up.

So this works which is where oauth redirects to after user accepts prompts:

```py
def oauth_redir(request):
    u=Employee.objects.filter(dashboard_user=request.user)
    if not u:
        u=Employee.objects.create(dashboard_user=request.user)
    else:
        u=u[0]
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=request.GET.get("state"))
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URL
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.build_absolute_uri().replace("http:","https:"))

    #saving credentials for future use
    credentials = flow.credentials
    if not Emp_google_creds.objects.filter(employee=u):
        Emp_google_creds.objects.create(
        token= credentials.token,
        refresh_token= credentials.refresh_token,
        token_uri = credentials.token_uri,
        client_id = credentials.client_id,
        client_secret= credentials.client_secret,
        scopes = " ".join(credentials.scopes),
        employee = u
        )
    else:
        creds=Emp_google_creds.objects.get(employee=u)
        creds.token = credentials.token,
        creds.refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token,
        creds.token_uri = credentials.token_uri,
        creds.client_id = credentials.client_id,
        creds.client_secret = credentials.client_secret,
        creds.scopes = " ".join(credentials.scopes),
        creds.save()


    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        print(credentials, credentials.valid, credentials.expiry)
        # credentials.refresh(Request())
        # return redirect("/calendar/cal_auth/")
    try:
        service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Calendar API
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found.')
            return

        # Prints the start and name of the next 10 events
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            print(start, event['summary'])

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
    print("end of redir func")
    return render(request,"schedule.html")
```

this loads the schedule as expected. however if you refresh in order to use the stored credentials they never work, they never refresh, i'm unsure on what to do.

```py
def calendar_home(request):
    u = Employee.objects.filter(dashboard_user=request.user)
    if not u:
        u = Employee.objects.create(dashboard_user=request.user)
    else:
        u = u[0]

    print(Emp_google_creds.objects.filter(employee=u))
    if not Emp_google_creds.objects.filter(employee=u):
        return redirect("/calendar/cal_auth/")
    else:
        creds=Emp_google_creds.objects.filter(employee=u)[0]
        gcreds=google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(creds.to_dict())
        if not gcreds or not gcreds.valid:
            print(gcreds, gcreds.valid, gcreds.expiry)
            # gcreds.refresh(Request())
            return redirect("/calendar/cal_auth/")
        try:
            service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=gcreds)

            # Call the Calendar API
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
            print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
            events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                                  maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                                  orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = events_result.get('items', [])

            if not events:
                print('No upcoming events found.')
                return

            # Prints the start and name of the next 10 events
            for event in events:
                start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                print(start, event['summary'])

        except HttpError as error:
            print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
    return render(request,"schedule.html")
```

basically this:

```
print(gcreds, gcreds.valid, gcreds.expiry) => 
<google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object at 0x7f322a00b340> False 2022-06-03 14:44:02.232624
```

and if i comment the redirect out i get:

```
('invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found.', {'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'The OAuth client was not found.'})
```

caused on this line:

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through all of this last week.  Maybe try building the credentials manually like I did instead of using Credentials.from_authorized_user_info().  I found out the hard way that Google likes to change things without updating their documentation.

```
    user_creds = json.loads(Emp_google_creds.objects.filter(employee=u)[0])
    creds=Credentials(
    token=user_creds['token'],
    refresh_token=user_creds['refresh_token'],
    token_uri=user_creds['token_uri'],
    client_id=user_creds['client_id'],
    client_secret=user_creds['client_secret']
    )
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: oh man you weren't right, but you were right...

Further inverstigation revealed that for some reason when i saved the information on the database it was saved with a tuple format as a string -> so token was "('<actual token>',)" and so on for every single element. anyway investigating what caused this next, but a quick fix revealed it is working, the comented out refresh method actually refreshes the token...
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request -> is what's called in the refresh.